# Passing the Parallel API tests in PettingZoo for custom multi-agent environment

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning, pettingzoo

```
from pettingzoo.test import (
    parallel_api_test,
    parallel_seed_test,
    max_cycles_test,
    performance_benchmark,
)
```

I have a custom multiagent environment that extends **ParallelEnv**, and since I passed the *parallel_api_test*,

I plan to pass the other ones as well before starting training:

1. **parallel_seed_test**

```
...
  File "D:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pettingzoo\test\seed_test.py", line 139, in parallel_seed_test
    check_environment_deterministic_parallel(env1, env2, num_cycles)
  File "D:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pettingzoo\test\seed_test.py", line 108, in check_environment_deterministic_parallel
    assert data_equivalence(actions1, actions2), "Incorrect action seeding"
```

I have no idea how to pass this one. I tried adding `np.random.seed()` statements in my observation_space and action_space functions, but I don't know how to get deterministic actions. Please advise. Are there any steps I can follow to pass the seed test and make my environment results reproducible?

2. **max_cycles_test**

```
...
  File "D:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pettingzoo\test\max_cycles_test.py", line 6, in max_cycles_test
    parallel_env = mod.parallel_env(max_cycles=max_cycles)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MultiAgentHighway' object has no attribute 'parallel_env'
```

I'm not sure how to use this? I have `end_of_sim` as the maximum number of steps in the simulation before which the simulation is closed forcefully?

3. **performance_benchmark**: Had to convert my `ParallelEnv` to `AEC` with `parallel_to_aec()` to use this.

```
2466.7955100048803 turns per second
123.33977550024402 cycles per second
Finished performance benchmark
```

How do I evaluate these numbers? Please advise.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I would suggest to read first the [corresponding documentation](https://pettingzoo.farama.org/1.24.3/content/environment_tests/), or the code itself (eg [`parallel_seed_test`](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo/blob/1.24.3/pettingzoo/test/seed_test.py#L135), [`max_cycles_test`](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo/blob/1.24.3/pettingzoo/test/max_cycles_test.py#L4), [`performance_benchmark`](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo/blob/1.24.3/pettingzoo/test/performance_benchmark.py#L7)) if something is missing from the docs.